# Scheduled task doesnt execute my powershell script

Tags: windows, bash, powershell, script, scheduled-tasks

I have a powershell script that download an antivirus update daily. When i execute the script manually, it works perfectly, but in the Scheduled task doesnt work. Only opens the .ps file that contains the code of the script (It opens in notepad). I dont know whats happening. This is the script:

```
remove-item E:\Update\* -Recurse
#Proxy auth
$Username="daril.aleman"
$Password="MyPassword"
$WebProxy = New-Object
System.Net.WebProxy("http://proxy.example.com:3128",$true)
$url="The.url.of.download.com/file.zip"

$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.Proxy=$Webproxy 
$client.proxy.Credentials = New-Object
System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password)
$client.DownloadFile($url, "E:\Update\Daily_Update.zip")
Set-Location E:\Update\ 
$Unzip = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$FileName = "Daily_Update.zip" 
$ZipFile = $Unzip.NameSpace((Get-Location).Path + "\$FileName") 
$Destination = $Unzip.namespace((Get-Location).Path) 
$Destination.Copyhere($ZipFile.items())
```

Comment: Do you have notepad configured to open .ps files?

Comment: In `Actions` you should choose action `start program` in program you write `PowerShell.exe` and in Arguments you write `-File "C:\path\script.ps1"` then it should get executed via PowerShell

Comment: What anti-virus are you using that can't update automatically?

Comment: I live in Cuba, we dont access to internet like you.

Comment: @DarilAlemán I lol'ed a bit at that.

Comment: Oh. I am sorry. I thought you were running some bizzare AV solution. I hope your internet connection improves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the settings you need:

**Action:** Start a program

**Program/script:** Powershell.exe

**Add arguments:** -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -FILE "C:\path\script.ps1"

EXAMPLE: https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/17736-run-powershell-scripts-from-task-scheduler